# Writing an encrypted mail via Exchange Web Services

Tags: email, service, exchange-server, web, encryption

I would like to send an encrypted  EMail Message with Exchange WEb Services using C#. 
Is there any possibillity? 
Thanks 

Edit:
My Mail body encrypter:

```
        public static byte[] encry(string body, ContentTyp typ, string to )
    {
        X509Certificate2 cert = GetMailCertificate(to);
        StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
        msg.AppendLine(string.Format("Content-Type: text/{0}; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"", typ.ToString()));
        msg.AppendLine("Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit");
        msg.AppendLine();
        msg.AppendLine(body);
        EnvelopedCms envelope = new EnvelopedCms(new ContentInfo(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg.ToString())));
        CmsRecipient recipient = new CmsRecipient(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, cert);
        envelope.Encrypt(recipient);
        //System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(envelope.Encode());
        return envelope.Encode();
    }
```

Main

```
 byte [] con = encrypted.encry("test", encrypted.ContentTyp.plain, "test@server.com");
        EmailMessage msg1 = new EmailMessage(_server);
        msg1.MimeContent = new MimeContent("UTF-8", con);
        msg1.ToRecipients.Add("user@server.com");

        msg1.InternetMessageHeaders = ??
        msg1.Send();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to S/Mime encryption, then you'll have to create the encrypted message according to [RFC 3852](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3852) and [RFC 4134](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4134). After you've done that, you can send the message.

Using the EWS Managed API, this can be done as follows:

```
var item = new EmailMessage(service);
item.MimeContent = new MimeContent(Encoding.ASCII.HeaderName, content);
// Set recipient infos, etc.
item.Send();
```

EDIT:
You should add the standard headers like From, To, Date, Subject, etc. And the content-type.

```
Subject: Test
From: "sender" <sender@yourcompany.com>
To: "recipient" <recipient@othercompany.com>
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=signed-data; name=smime.p7m
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=smime.p7m

Your encrypted body goes here
```

Just use a StringWriter put all that together. The result is your MIME body.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like to use my own X509Certificate2 which I get from the LDAP.

Comment: Since you need to perform the whole encryption yourself, that is not a problem.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I know how to create an encrypted MailMessage with the mailMessage Class. Perhabs I can just use this Header and bind them to my EMailMessage?

Comment: So you already have an encrypted message in MIME format? Then just go ahead and create an EmailMessage as shown in the example.

Comment: Yes I already have an encrypted message in MIME format. But this message is MailMessage and not EMailMessage. I can not cast MailMessage into EMailMessage right?

Comment: You mean the MailMessage (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) from the .NET Framework? Where did you get that from?
You won't get the MIME structure from that object. How do you construct the encrypted mail?

Comment: Yes MailMessage from .Net You can create an alternateView

Comment: If you already have all that data, don't bother creating a MailMessage. Just create the required headers yourself. BTW, since you encrypted you message, you should set the smime-type parameter to "enveloped-data". See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4134#section-5.3 for an example.

Comment: OK I see your point. How would that work in my example? What should I put into my Header content:  _msg.MimeContent = new MimeContent(Encoding.ASCII.HeaderName, content);

Comment: I changed the CreateAlternateView method and return now a Byte[] array with the content of envelope.Encode() I put the Byte array into the MimeContent("UTF-8",Byte array Content) but my message isn't encrypted. It arives as a normal email.

Comment: I added my current code on the top. I don't know how I can add the header information. I also got an CryptographicException in this line envelope.Encrypt(recipient). The program runs anyhow with this exception but still with an empty non encrypted message.

Comment: The headers are not suppposed to be encrypted. The encrypted data contains a standard mimepart. In case of a simple message, this would be the content-type set to text/plain, followed by an empty line and the message itself. Then you build another mimepart according to my example above and put your encrypted data in the content.

Comment: Hello again. OK no I receive an encrypted messagen but I can not open it. ErrorMessage in Outlook: "Can't open this item. Your Digital ID name can not be found by the underlying security system" I created two Byte arrays one with the header content like you wrote: Subject, From, Content Type etc. and a second for my encyrpted body( The method called "encry" which returns a byte array) Then I added the two and put them into the Mime Content. The Mail goes out but I can't open it.

Comment: That's because you need to add your own certificate to the EnvelopedCMS as well - i.e. another CmsRecipient.